# Locked outside remote server

Tags: ssh, centos7

I was improving the security of my server, added my public key to the authorized_keys and disabled the possibility of access by password and by root, however, while I was creating a new user, I lost my ssh session and now I'm locked outside.

These were the configurations I did:

```
$ vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
PermitRootLogin no
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Since I have my public key configured, is there a way to access with some default user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the user you were working with in first place was root and you have configured the public key for root so when you disabled root from login with ssh you can't even use your public key ...

The best solution is too use a console connection if your VPS hosing provides one, otherwise contact them and ask for help

Comment: As you said, it has to be the Hosting Provider fixing the issue. Thanks